# Relationship betwen eigenvectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvector, eigenvalues

Suppose that we have two matrices A and B. Matrix B is taken from A with one row and one column deleted. On the other hand A is n*n matrix and B is (n-1)*(n-1) matrix and is created by deleting last row and last column of B. 
If we are given eigenvalues of A, is it possible to use them to calculate eigenvalues of B?
Thanks.

EDIT: I take the liberty of rewriting the question, based on information gleaned from the comments.

If we know the eigenvalues of (the adjacency matrix of) a graph $G$, can we use that information to calculate the eigenvalues of a graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by deleting a vertex (and all edges adjacent to that vertex)?

Presumably, the answer is "no", as it will depend on which vertex we remove, so let me ask for less: what can we say about the eigenvalues of $G'$, from just knowing the eigenvalues of $G$?

Comment: MO is intended for questions at the mathematics PhD student level and above.  I've voted to close.

Comment: @AndyPutman Although I think the question could be improved, it doesn't seem trivial to me. (E.g. Cauchy interlacing in the self-adjoint case)

Comment: @YemonChoi :  Hmm...if you think it is interesting then I'll withdraw my objection.

Comment: Sorry for my English, but I think it's not that trivial it looks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @FaridAla Are there extra conditions on your matrices A and B? If B is an arbitrary matrix then it may be hard to relate the spectrum of A with the spectrum of B in any useful way

Comment: There are no extra conditions on matrices. Actually A is adjacency matrix of a graph and B is adjacency matrix of that graph where one of it's node is removed.

Comment: If the only information you have is the spectrum of $A$, then you cannot compute the spectrum of $B$.  Did you mean to ask a different question, e.g., something about improving runtime performance?

Comment: No, I'm not going to improve run time performance. I want to use it to calculate normalized cuts in a graph for image segmentation.

Comment: @FaridAla I don't understand your thought processes: you say "there are no extra conditions on matrices" but then you say "A is the adjacency matrix of a graph" -- this is *an incredible amount of extra structure*! Not every matrix behaves like the adjacency matrix of a graph!

Comment: If you are interested in eigenvalues of adjacency matrices then this information should be included in your question. Please edit it, and then flag for the question to be reopened.